# Ignite JTS WGS84

Tags: ignite, jts, wgs84

I have been trying to use JTS within Apache Ignite in correlation with GPS coordinates.
So far I am not sure how or if those could interact. For example if I calculate a distance between two geometries, I will have a planar distance, but how would I convert it back to distance at the surface of the earth ?

For reference here is some code I used, I am not sure the transformations are correct though, but it's not the root of the problem:

```
Coordinate coord1 = convertToRect(resultCoord.y, resultCoord.x, 0.0);
Coordinate coord2 = convertToRect(latitude, longitude, 0.0);
double dist = new GeometryFactory().createPoint(coord1).distance(new GeometryFactory().createPoint(coord2));
```

...

```
private Coordinate convertToRect(Double lat, Double lon, Double alt) {
    MathTransform ecefTransform =  org.geotools.referencing.CRS.findMathTransform(DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84_3D, DefaultGeocentricCRS.CARTESIAN);           

    GeometryFactory geometryFactory = JTSFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory(null);
    Point p = geometryFactory.createPoint(new Coordinate(lat, lon, alt));

    Geometry tp = JTS.transform(p, ecefTransform);
    return tp.getCoordinate();
}
```

So maybe JTS is not meant to be used to perform geolocation on earth ? Otherwise would you know where I could find references of such usage ?

For reference the used libs:

```
compile 'org.opengis:geoapi:3.0.1'
compile 'org.geotools:gt-api:2.7.5'
compile 'org.geotools:gt-shapefile:2.7.5'
compile group: 'org.apache.ignite', name: 'ignite-geospatial', version: '2.5.2'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for distance in meters, you could use the GeoTools libraries GeodeticCalculator.  As a shorthand, JTS handles geometry and GeoTools (and other libraries) are designed to help with geography.

http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/referencing/calculator.html
http://docs.geotools.org/stable/javadocs/org/geotools/referencing/GeodeticCalculator.html

Comment: It looks like the distance calculator is on a plane and not a real distance on the curved surface of earth.

Comment: The GeodeticCalculator calculates distance on an ellipsoid and returns distance in meters.  http://docs.geotools.org/stable/javadocs/org/geotools/referencing/GeodeticCalculator.html#GeodeticCalculator--

Comment: The distance in JTS is indeed distance in a Cartesian plane.

Comment: Calculating the distance outside ignite is working well with geotools (or haversine...). My problem is I would like to use the JTS function provided by Apache Ignite by directly calling them to find positions, intersections... The distance is one of the simple use.

Comment: From a brief look at the Apache Ignite source code, it looks like the project would have to add support for calculating distance in meters.  Other geometric calculations should work just fine.  (I.e., applying topological predicates and forming new geometries should work.)